# Why does Heroku tell me that my version of git (2.1.0) has serious security vulnerabilities?

Tags: git, heroku, homebrew

*Heroku toolbelt* seems current:

```
-bash> heroku --version
Your version of git is 2.1.0. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
heroku-toolbelt/3.22.1 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

According to *homebrew*, `git` is current:

```
-bash> brew outdated git

-bash> which git
/usr/local/bin/git

-bash> git --version
git version 2.1.0
```

I realize that at the time of this writing [the current source code release of Git is version 2.2.1](http://git-scm.com/download/mac) - but that is quite bleeding edge, and even [the official Git website is shipping version 2.0.1 of Git for the Mac platform](http://git-scm.com/download/mac).

Comment: I am also using Homebrew, but I get `Error: git-2.1.0 already installed` when running `brew upgrade git`. How did you get all the way up to `2.2.1` via Homebrew?

Comment: I'm no Homebrew expert, but have you run `brew doctor || brew update`?

Comment: Bingo! `brew update` did the trick (followed by `brew upgrade git`). Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A vulnerability affecting case-insensitive filesystems was recently uncovered (and subsequently fixed) in Git; you can find more details about it in [this blogpost](http://git-blame.blogspot.ie/2014/12/git-1856-195-205-214-and-221-and.html) by Junio Hamano (Git's current maintainer), and in [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27848422/2541573).

The Heroku utility is detecting that you're running a version of Git (v2.1.0) in which the vulnerability in question is present, and that you better upgrade, lest you fall prey to ill-intentioned folks.

At the time of writing this, the latest version of Git is v2.2.1. Since you're using Homebrew, upgrading to that version can be achieved by running

```sh
brew doctor       # checks for potential problems
brew update       # fetches the latest list of formulas
brew upgrade git  # self-explanatory
```

(Note that Homebrew won't detect that a new version is available if you haven't run `brew update` in a while.)

As for...

> even the official Git website is shipping version 2.0.1 of Git for the Mac platform

be aware that the [Git installer for Mac OS X](http://git-scm.com/download/mac) is always a few versions behind the current Git release (available via Homebrew). That's one more reason to use a package manager instead of an installer: getting the latest version of Git (and other pieces of software) hot out of the oven!

Answer (score 2):

There was a critical vulnerability [announced (and fixed) recently](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1853266), affecting Windows and Mac versions of Git.

Atlassian has a [good writeup](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2014/12/securing-your-git-server/):

> A critical vulnerability was [identified in Git last week](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1853266). This has been fixed in all maintained versions of Git (v1.8.5.6, v1.9.5, v2.0.5, v2.1.4, and v2.2.1) so upgrading is the best way to protect yourself. However a sensible second step is to secure your Git hosting server, so that pushes containing malicious trees are automatically rejected. This will prevent attackers from exploiting users who have yet to upgrade their local versions of Git.

The same article goes on to explain how to protect yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - though I am accepting @jubobs answer because it immediately solved my `brew` predicament. I appreciate your time and effort nonetheless.